# Vertex factor for $\frac{g}{4} (A_{\nu}A^{\nu})^2$ in QED

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams

Suppose we had an interaction term $\frac{g}{4} (A_{\nu}A^{\nu})^2$ in QED. What would the vertex rule be? I believe it would have four vector indices such as $g^{\mu\rho}g^{\sigma\nu}$ and it would be symmetric in the four indices; but I do not know how to derive this exactly.

Comment: Funny that this question showed up here precisely during the time when students were working on my take-home final exam that included this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the interaction as
$$
\frac{g}{4} A^\rho A^\nu A^\sigma A^\mu  g_{\rho \nu} g_{\sigma \mu}
$$

Suppose you have a 4-point function to compute with the following external polarization vector

$$
\epsilon^{\mu_1}(p_1),\,\epsilon^{\mu_2}(p_2)\,,\epsilon^{\mu_3}(p_3)\,,\epsilon^{\mu_4}(p_4)
$$

The rule is then

$$
i \frac{g}{4}\epsilon^{\mu_1}(p_1)\,\epsilon^{\mu_2}(p_2)\,\epsilon^{\mu_3}(p_3)\,\epsilon^{\mu_4}(p_4)g_{\rho \nu} g_{\sigma \mu}\left(\delta^{\mu_1}_\rho\delta^{\mu_2}_\nu\delta^{\mu_3}_\sigma\delta^{\mu_4}_\mu  + \textit{perm} \right)
$$

where *perm* means all possible permutation of $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3,\mu_4$.

**EDIT**

This is how I compute the permutation.

In the following I try to simplify the notation and I'll set

$$\delta^1_\mu=\delta^{\mu_1}_\mu\\
\delta^{1\,2}_{\sigma\,\mu} = \delta^1_\sigma\delta^2_\mu + \delta^1_\mu\delta^2_\sigma\\
g_{12}=g_{\mu_1\,\mu_2}$$

I fix one leg and do the permutation on the other legs, and then I just permute the result by permuting the fixed leg. For example,

I choose to fix $\mu_1$. The result is

$$g_{\rho\nu}g_{\sigma\mu} \delta^1_\rho\left[\delta^2_\nu \delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\mu}+\delta^2_\sigma \delta^{3\,4}_{\nu\,\mu}+\delta^2_\mu \delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\nu}\right]$$

then I have to do the permutation of $2,3,4$ which is equivalent to do the permutation of $\nu,\sigma,\mu$.

The result is then

$$
\begin{align}
&g_{\rho\nu}g_{\sigma\mu} \left[\delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\nu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\mu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\sigma}\delta^{3\,4}_{\nu\,\mu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\mu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\nu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\nu\sigma}\delta^{3\,4}_{\rho\,\mu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\mu\nu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\rho}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\sigma\mu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\rho\,\nu}\right]\\
&=8g_{12}g_{34} + g_{\rho\nu}g_{\sigma\mu} \left[\delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\sigma}\delta^{3\,4}_{\nu\,\mu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\mu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\nu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\nu\sigma}\delta^{3\,4}_{\rho\,\mu}+\delta^{1\,2}_{\mu\nu}\delta^{3\,4}_{\sigma\,\rho}\right]
\end{align}$$

I'll just compute one term inside the brakets (actually, the other ones are equals)

$$
 g_{\rho\nu}g_{\sigma\mu} \delta^{1\,2}_{\rho\sigma}\delta^{3\,4}_{\nu\,\mu} = 2(g_{13}g_{24}+g_{14}g_{23})
$$

Then, I end up with

$$
\frac{ig}{4}8(g_{12}g_{34} + g_{14}g_{32}+g_{13}g_{42})
$$

Comment: Okay, given 24 permutations and a factor of $\frac14$ out front, would that yield a vertex rule of $6ig (g^{\rho\nu}g^{\sigma\mu} + g^{\rho\sigma} g^{\nu\mu} + g^{\rho\mu}g^{\sigma\nu}$? Or am I over counting?

Comment: I meant $2ig(g^{\rho\nu} g^{\sigma\mu} + g^{\rho\sigma} g^{\nu\mu} + g^{\rho\mu} g^{\sigma\mu})$.

Comment: @AgriculturalEnergy I edited my answer. By matching my convention with yours, I get the same factor of 2.